# Mysql sub select is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table like this :

```
-------------------------------
| id | valid_until |  username|
-------------------------------
| 1  | 2020-01-01  |   user1  |
-------------------------------  
| 1  | 2020-01-01  |   user2  |
-------------------------------  
| 1  | 2020-01-02  |   user3  |
-------------------------------  
| 1  | 2020-01-02  |   user4  |
-------------------------------  
| 1  | 2020-01-03  |   user5  |
-------------------------------  
| 1  | 2020-01-03  |   user6  |
-------------------------------  
| 1  | 2020-01-03  |   user7  |
-------------------------------
```

This is the user subscription table, `valid_until` says when the subscription will end up.

I want to know active subscription in each day, So I have a range, for example, `2020-01-01` TO `2020-01-03` and here is my query :

```
SELECT 
    valid_until qva,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(iod.id) AS ct
        FROM
            `order_detail` iod
        WHERE
            valid_until > qva)
FROM
    `order_detail`
WHERE
    valid_until >= '2020-01-01'
        AND valid_until <= '2020-01-03'
GROUP BY qva
```

But this query is too slow, What is the problem with my query?  Response time (230 sec)

Comment: provide `EXPLAIN` of the query

Comment: Why do  you use the function DATE()? `valid_until` is a DATE.

Comment: I've removed the DATE.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? Which version?

Comment: Is there an index on `order_detail(valid_until )`? Otherwise the DBMS must read the complete table again and again. And why `COUNT(iod.id)`? A table's ID must never be null, so why the not null detection? You simply want `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Yes we have an index on valid_until, You are right I changed COUNT(id) to COUNT(*), but still super slow.

Comment: @Ali show the explain of the query

Comment: Your query doesn't look right.  It sounds like you want three rows returned, but you won't get results for dates that aren't the valid_until for at least one record.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is invalid according to the SQL standard. You have `GROUP BY qva` (and using the alias name here is usually not allowed, but in MySQL and MariaDB it is), but you don't apply an aggregate function on the subquery result. MySQL is known for violating the standard here and they silently apply `ANY_VALUE` on such unaggregated expressions.

This makes the query slow. For each order in the date range the count is evaluated, only to pick one of those counts per date at the very end.

So, let's build the query up from scratch. You want one result row for each day in the given date range. That is:

```
select distinct valid_until
where valid_until between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-01-03'
from order_detail;
```

Then, for each of these dates you want to get the count. You can do this in a subquery as in your original query. I suppose it must be `>=` instead of `>` though, as an order valid until a day is still valid that day (or at least this is what I'd expect).

```
SELECT 
  dates.day,
  (
    select count(*) 
    from order_detail od
    where od.valid_until >= dates.day
  ) as ct
FROM
(
  select distinct valid_until as day
  where valid_until between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-01-03'
  from order_detail
) dates
order by dates.day;
```

(This assumes that `valid_until` is a mere date. If it's a datetime, you'll have to adjust this query a little.)

**UPDATE:**

As ysth told you in the request comments, your query will get you only days in the given range that exist as `valid_until` in your table. So does mine. If you wanted the three days regardless, you'd have to replace the subquery and make it independent from the table, e.g.

```
FROM
(
  select date '2020-01-01' as day union all
  select date '2020-01-02' as day union all
  select date '2020-01-03' as day
) dates
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a cumulative count of `valid_until` from the latest date to the earliest:

```
select valid_until, count(*) day_count,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by valid_until desc) as count_as_of_day
from order_details od
group by valid_until;
```

If you want this for a range of dates, then use a subquery:

```
select od.*
from (select valid_until, count(*) day_count,
             sum(count(*)) over (order by valid_until desc) as count_as_of_day
      from order_details od
      group by valid_until
     ) od
where valid_until >= :from and valid_until <= :to
```